# How do I parse Json data with Gson when not everything is labelled

Tags: java, json, gson

I have happily been using Google `Gson` to parse extract some JSON metadata of the form

```
{
  "lowlevel": {
    "average_loudness": 0.570070445538
  },
  "rhythm": {
     "beats_count": 502, 
     "bpm": 128.347702026
  }, 
  "tonal": {
     "chords_changes_rate": 0.0534749031067
     "tuning_diatonic_strength": 0.431238204241, 
     "tuning_equal_tempered_deviation": 0.164615109563, 
     "tuning_frequency": 434.193115234, 
     "tuning_nontempered_energy_ratio": 0.847496032715
  }
}
```

Using this

```
public class AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper
{
    private AcousticBrainzLowLevelRhythm rhythm;
    private AcousticBrainzLowLevelTonal tonal;

    public AcousticBrainzLowLevelRhythm getRhythm()
    {
        return rhythm;
    }

    public void setRhythm(AcousticBrainzLowLevelRhythm rhythm)
    {
        this.rhythm = rhythm;
    }

    public AcousticBrainzLowLevelTonal getTonal()
    {
        return tonal;
    }

    public void setTonal(AcousticBrainzLowLevelTonal tonal)
    {
        this.tonal = tonal;
    }
}
```

and

```
 AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper low = gson.fromJson(result, AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper.class) ;
```

(Full JSON can be seen [here](https://acousticbrainz.org/api/v1/96685213-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35/low-level))

but now the API has been extended to allow multiple lookups such as this [url](https://acousticbrainz.org/api/v1/low-level?recording_ids=96685213-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35;abb11b76-3103-4716-b388-434c4479367a)

which now returns

```
{
  "96685213-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35": {
    "0": {
      "lowlevel": {
        "average_loudness": 0.570070445538
      },
      "rhythm": {
        "beats_count": 502, 
        "bpm": 128.347702026
      }, 
      "tonal": {
        "chords_changes_rate": 0.0534749031067
        "tuning_diatonic_strength": 0.431238204241, 
        "tuning_equal_tempered_deviation": 0.164615109563, 
        "tuning_frequency": 434.193115234, 
        "tuning_nontempered_energy_ratio": 0.847496032715
     }
  }
  .....
  "78787888-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35": {
    "0": {
      "lowlevel": {
      ......
  ..
```

The difference being that the json doesn't define what "96685213-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35" and "78787888-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35" are, or what "0" is.

So I know what they represent (MusicBrainzRecording and offset) but I cannot create a class like  `AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper` to represent this, so how do I parse this new api.

**Update**
I tried creating

```
  public class AcousticBrainzLowLevelList
{
    private Map<String, AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper> data = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper> data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and then calling

```
 AcousticBrainzLowLevelList lowMap = gson.fromJson(result, AcousticBrainzLowLevelList.class) ;
```

but nothing get added to the map. Unsuprisingly because `data` I dont' see how can i give a name since there is no consistent name at the top level.

Comment: I think this is a `Map`.

Comment: Right, so i guess I need to create a wrapper class for AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper that contains map of them, not clear on what it should look like.

Comment: I think you should have a key `String` map of your current `AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper` like this `Map<String, AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper>`

Comment: Isnt it more complex than that because at top level there each contains "0" (Xml is so much easier to understand !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your input JSON could be parsed to produce a Java class of type `Map<String,Map<Integer,AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper>>` :

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<Integer,AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper>>>(){}.getType();
Map<String,Map<Integer,AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper>> result = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

Comment: HI, I dont seem able to access com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken says has protected access ?

Comment: You beat me to it, I just finished testing the same solution :)

Comment: @PaulTaylor he forgot `{}`, try like this: `Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String,Map<Integer,AcousticBrainzLowlevelWrapper>>>(){}.getType();`

Comment: Brilliant, that works. My only question is does the outer map it use a sortedmap, if not can it be so is same order as the json

Comment: @PaulTaylor not sure. Just try replacing Map with SortedMap

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote it, I might as well post it:
Similar to Maurice's answer

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    private final static String jsonSingle = 
        "{ \"attribute1\": \"value1\",  \"attribute2\": \"value2\" }";

    private final static String jsonMultiple = 
        "{\n" +
        "  \"96685213-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35\": {\n" +
        "    \"0\": { \"attribute1\": \"value1\", \"attribute2\": \"value2\" }\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  \"78787888-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35\": {\n" +
        "    \"0\": { \"attribute1\": \"value3\",  \"attribute2\": \"value4\" }\n" +
        "}}";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyBean bean = new Gson().fromJson(jsonSingle, MyBean.class);
        System.out.println(bean);

        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, MyBean>>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, String> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMultiple, type);
        System.out.println(myMap);
    }   
}
```

MyBean class:

```
class MyBean {
    String attribute1;
    String attribute2;

    public String getAttribute1() {
        return attribute1;
    }

    public void setAttribute1(String attribute1) {
        this.attribute1 = attribute1;
    }

    public String getAttribute2() {
        return attribute2;
    }

    public void setAttribute2(String attribute2) {
        this.attribute2 = attribute2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyBean: <attribute1: " + attribute1 + " | " + "attribute2: " + attribute2 + ">";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
MyBean: <attribute1: value1 | attribute2: value2>
```

and

```
{96685213-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35={0=MyBean: <attribute1: value1 | attribute2: value2>}, 78787888-a25c-4678-9a13-abd9ec81cf35={0=MyBean: <attribute1: value3 | attribute2: value4>}}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this, but the other answer is more closely aligned to my data.